# How can i limit Panning and make show only one city on my MapView?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to find out how can i make show only one city on my MapView. Is there a way to limit panning map? if setMapBoundaries  is the one that i search,  how can i pass the values in it?

Here my mapview:

```
                        <MapView
                            customMapStyle={mapStyle}
                            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                            style={{ flex: 1 }}
                            region={{
                                latitude: 40.1467,
                                longitude: 26.4086,
                                latitudeDelta: 1.1922,
                                longitudeDelta: 1.1221
                            }}

                            rotateEnabled={false}
                            minZoomLevel={9}

                        >
                            
                        </MapView>
```